# At creating a ROS package by hand

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tutorials, creating a ROS package by hand

To see one example of why specifying these dependencies is useful, try executing the following commands rospack commands:

rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags foobar
rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=lflags foobar

what is the "--attrib" , "cflags" and "lflags"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35407/at-creating-a-ros-package-by-hand/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In manifest files of packages that export libraries, you can see something like this (taken from roscpp's maifest file):

```
<export>
  <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include `rosboost-cfg --cflags`" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lros `rosboost-cfg --lflags thr
</export>
```

With `rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags roscpp` you'll get the value of the attribute cflags as specified in roscpp's manifest.xml. cflags exports are used by CMake to build up all compiler flags for building a package, lflags are used for linker flags respectively.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2